# UPNP - Bind between Device and Services (miniupnp)

Tags: c, linux, upnp, miniupnpc

I am using miniupnp SW package running on my router. In order to list all available devices / services on my LAN network, I used 'listdevice' application, which basically query miniupnpc to discover all devices / services and then print them out.

Can someone please explain how can I understand, which service is belong to each device?

See an example table below:

```
1: urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:Layer3Forwarding:1 
 http://192.168.1.1:5000/rootDesc.xml
 uuid:63ce4f39-1485-4bd6-ba33-bb1ec09dc1cf::urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:Layer3Forwarding:1
2: uuid:63ce4f39-1485-4bd6-ba33-bb1ec09dc1cf       
 http://192.168.1.1:5000/rootDesc.xml
 uuid:63ce4f39-1485-4bd6-ba33-bb1ec09dc1cf
3: uuid:63ce4f39-1485-4bd6-ba33-bb1ec09dc1c0       
 http://192.168.1.1:5000/rootDesc.xml
 uuid:63ce4f39-1485-4bd6-ba33-bb1ec09dc1c0
4: uuid:63ce4f39-1485-4bd6-ba33-bb1ec09dc1c1       
 http://192.168.1.1:5000/rootDesc.xml
 uuid:63ce4f39-1485-4bd6-ba33-bb1ec09dc1c1
5: urn:schemas-upnp-org:device:WANConnectionDevice:1
 http://192.168.1.1:5000/rootDesc.xml
 uuid:63ce4f39-1485-4bd6-ba33-bb1ec09dc1c1::urn:schemas-upnp-org:device:WANConnectionDevice:1
6: urn:schemas-upnp-org:device:WANDevice:1         
 http://192.168.1.1:5000/rootDesc.xml
 uuid:63ce4f39-1485-4bd6-ba33-bb1ec09dc1c0::urn:schemas-upnp-org:device:WANDevice:1
7: urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:WANIPConnection:1  
 http://192.168.1.1:5000/rootDesc.xml
 uuid:63ce4f39-1485-4bd6-ba33-bb1ec09dc1c1::urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:WANIPConnection:1
8: urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:WANCommonInterfaceConfig:1
 http://192.168.1.1:5000/rootDesc.xml
 uuid:63ce4f39-1485-4bd6-ba33-bb1ec09dc1c0::urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:WANCommonInterfaceConfig:1
9: urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:WANPPPConnection:1 
 http://192.168.1.1:5000/rootDesc.xml
 uuid:63ce4f39-1485-4bd6-ba33-bb1ec09dc1c1::urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:WANPPPConnection:1
10: upnp:rootdevice                                 
 http://192.168.1.1:5000/rootDesc.xml
 uuid:63ce4f39-1485-4bd6-ba33-bb1ec09dc1cf::upnp:rootdevice
11: urn:schemas-upnp-org:device:InternetGatewayDevice:1
 http://192.168.1.1:5000/rootDesc.xml
 uuid:63ce4f39-1485-4bd6-ba33-bb1ec09dc1cf::urn:schemas-upnp-org:device:InternetGatewayDevice:1
12: urn:microsoft.com:service:X_MS_MediaReceiverRegistrar:1
 http://192.168.1.1:8200/rootDesc.xml
 uuid:4d696e69-444c-164e-9d41-7e1fa325930c::urn:microsoft.com:service:X_MS_MediaReceiverRegistrar:1
13: urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:ConnectionManager:1
 http://192.168.1.1:8200/rootDesc.xml
 uuid:4d696e69-444c-164e-9d41-7e1fa325930c::urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:ConnectionManager:1
14: urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:ContentDirectory:1 
 http://192.168.1.1:8200/rootDesc.xml
 uuid:4d696e69-444c-164e-9d41-7e1fa325930c::urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:ContentDirectory:1
15: urn:schemas-upnp-org:device:MediaServer:1       
 http://192.168.1.1:8200/rootDesc.xml
 uuid:4d696e69-444c-164e-9d41-7e1fa325930c::urn:schemas-upnp-org:device:MediaServer:1
16: upnp:rootdevice                                 
 http://192.168.1.1:8200/rootDesc.xml
 uuid:4d696e69-444c-164e-9d41-7e1fa325930c::upnp:rootdevice
17: uuid:4d696e69-444c-164e-9d41-7e1fa325930c       
 http://192.168.1.1:8200/rootDesc.xml
 uuid:4d696e69-444c-164e-9d41-7e1fa325930c
```

Comment: @miniupnp - can you take a look?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "client"?

Comment: @jku - sorry, typo

Answer (score 2):

For this case, the response will actually do the trick for you.

Each Device will always be followed by his Services, so as can be seen in the table above, a device might offer no services, for example:

```
5: urn:schemas-upnp-org:device:WANConnectionDevice:1
http://192.168.1.1:5000/rootDesc.xml
uuid:63ce4f39-1485-4bd6-ba33-bb1ec09dc1c1::urn:schemas-upnp-org:device:WANConnectionDevice:1
```

Or can offer several services, for example:

```
6: urn:schemas-upnp-org:device:WANDevice:1         
http://192.168.1.1:5000/rootDesc.xml
uuid:63ce4f39-1485-4bd6-ba33-bb1ec09dc1c0::urn:schemas-upnp-org:device:WANDevice:1
7: urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:WANIPConnection:1  
http://192.168.1.1:5000/rootDesc.xml
uuid:63ce4f39-1485-4bd6-ba33-bb1ec09dc1c1::urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:WANIPConnection:1
8: urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:WANCommonInterfaceConfig:1
http://192.168.1.1:5000/rootDesc.xml
uuid:63ce4f39-1485-4bd6-ba33-bb1ec09dc1c0::urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:WANCommonInterfaceConfig:1
9: urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:WANPPPConnection:1 
http://192.168.1.1:5000/rootDesc.xml
uuid:63ce4f39-1485-4bd6-ba33-bb1ec09dc1c1::urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:WANPPPConnection:1
```